# C++ input validation for numeric input

Tags: c++, validation

I'm creating my own very simple program that allows the user to input a numeric value. At the moment the code works just fine, but I need a validation if else statement. This is what I have at the moment;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unsigned __int64 input = 0;
    char str[] = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm[]{};'#:@~,./<>?|!£$%^&*()";

    cout << "Insert a number" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (input % 2 == 0) 
    {
        cout << "Even!" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (input% 2 == 1)
        {
            cout << "Odd" << endl;
            cout << "Lets make it even shall we? " << "Your new number is... " << input + 1 << endl;
        }
        else if (isdigit(str[0]))
        {
            cout << "That isn't a number!" << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

The issue I am having is that if the user inputs anything that isn't a number, the value it returns is "Even".

I hope you guys and girls can help!
John

Comment: If you enter anything but a number, nothing is extracted from the stream and `input` stays 0. That assumes "anything but a number" does not include 123abc.

Comment: Ok thanks, how would you fix this? I'm a beginner!

Comment: You need to check for failure when you read input. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use token extraction (`>>`) for primary parsing. Once the extraction fails, your primary input is left in an unspecified state, which is terrible. Instead, read the input line by line and then process each line.

Also, **never** ignore the result of an input operation. That's just a flat error.

So, putting all this together, here's how you could handle this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    for (std::string line; std::cout << "Input: " && std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        std::cout << "We're parsing your line '" << line << "'\n";

        int n;
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        if (iss >> n >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF)
        {
            std::cout << "It was a number: " << n << "\n";
        }
        else if (line.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "You didn't say anything!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "We could not parse '" << line << "' as a number.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";
}
```

Note that all input operations (namely `>>` and `getline`) appear in immediate boolean contexts!

Comment: Thanks,but I don't really understand this code. I've been doing c++ for seven weeks now!

Comment: @JohnBrown: Then your homework for week 8 is to understand this code!

Comment: @JohnBrown: Glad you like it! More importantly, you're now in a position to answer 20% of all C++ questions on SO!

Comment: What variable name is being used for the input?

Comment: @JohnBrown: It's `line`, isn't it?

Comment: Woop, I thought it was :) I will get my head around this!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19725/discussion-between-john-brown-and-kerrek-sb)