# Not handling user input correctly

Tags: c++, user-input, cin, arrays

So, this program I am working on is not handling incorrect user input the way I want it to. The user should only be able to enter a 3-digit number for use later in a HotelRoom object constructor. Unfortunately, my instructor doesn't allow the use of string objects in his class (otherwise, I wouldn't have any problems, I think). Also, I am passing the roomNumBuffer to the constructor to create a const char pointer. I am currently using the iostream, iomanip, string.h, and limits preprocessor directives. The problem occurs after trying to enter too many chars for the roomNumBuffer. The following screenshot shows what happens:
[image]

The relevant code for this problem follows:

```
cout << endl << "Please enter the 3-digit room number: ";
do {        //loop to check user input
    badInput = false;
    cin.width(4);
    cin >> roomNumBuffer;
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        if(!isdigit(roomNumBuffer[x])) {        //check all chars entered are digits
            badInput = true;
        }
    }
    if(badInput) {
        cout << endl << "You did not enter a valid room number. Please try again: ";
    }
    cin.get();      //Trying to dum- any extra chars the user might enter
} while(badInput);

for(;;) {   //Infinite loop broken when correct input obtained
    cin.get();      //Same as above
    cout << "Please enter the room capacity: ";
    if(cin >> roomCap) {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
for(;;) {   //Infinite loop broken when correct input obtained
    cout << "Please enter the nightly room rate: ";
    if(cin >> roomRt) {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid rate" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's insane not to use `getline` as the first parsing step. [Do it like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13445220/596781).

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree, but I thought that using cin.width() might help with what I was trying to accomplish. I was having the same problem when I was trying **getline** though. How would I be able to take care of this problem when using it instead?

Answer (score 2):

Read an integer and test whether it's in the desired range:

```
int n;

if (!(std::cin >> n && n >= 100 && n < 1000))
{
    /* input error! */
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I need to have a char array to pass to the constructor (takes the char array and creates a const char pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Although Kerrek SB provide an approach how to address the problem, just to explain what when wrong with your approach: the integer array could successfully be read. The stream was in good state but you didn't reach a space. That is, to use your approach, you'd need to also test that the character following the last digit, i.e., the next character in the stream, is a whitespace of some sort:

```
if (std::isspace(std::cin.peek())) {
     // deal with funny input
}
```

It seems the error recovery for the first value isn't quite right, though. You probably also want to `ignore()` all characters until the end of the line.